# Other reasons or purposed for using the Pimpl Idoim

Tags: c++, design-patterns, pimpl-idiom

As the title suggests, I was wondering what other reasons, purposes or uses are there for the PImpl idiom other than reducing rebuild times.

Quoting an example from [**here**](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2017/02/87184.php):

> (thread locals need to be behind a pimpl wall; they
>   can't be exported directly

I don't understand what the user means, but I gather there are other *interesting* uses for the PImpl idiom,

Comment: This means that thread local variables should not exist in the declaration files as this causes the issues described in the Ticket. Also another benefit of using PImpl is reducing dependencies.

Comment: @N.Gerontidis you could perhaps write your reducing dependencies comment as an answer and elaborate a little more.

Answer (score 4):

From the book "*Effective C++ Third Edition*" by Scott Meyers (Item 31)

"*The key to this separation is replacement of dependencies on definitions
with dependencies on declarations. That’s the essence of minimizing
compilation dependencies: make your header files self-sufficient whenever
it’s practical, and when it’s not, depend on declarations in other
files, not definitions.*"

For example in this case, moving the thread local variable to the definition file there is one less compilation dependency because the thread_local.hpp is not included in the declaration file.